# How to add vlan without vconfig command?

Tags: linux, debian, vlan

Is there any way how to create vlan interface without using vconfig ? I have only KVM console and trunk port connected to the machine, so I cannot use apt as I do not have internet access. I defined vlans in /etc/network/interfaces but it does not work as vlan interfaces are not created. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i'll fix that.

Comment: How is it 'not constructive' ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.5 type vlan id 5
```

do not forget to make link UP:

```
ip link set eth0 up
ip link set eth0.5 up
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for (embedded device; minimal tools). 
And just for completion:
`ip link del eth0.5` to delete the vlan